# Detecting a "EBCDIC X'DF'" character in a file

Tags: character-encoding, ebcdic

Reading this document:

> PK19612: SENDMAIL TIMESOUT - SENDING OUT AN EMAIL THAT CONTAINS A EBCDIC X'DF'
> https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PK26459

The recommended fix is to:

> **Local fix**
> remove the x'DF' from the body of the email

How can a "X'DF'" character be detected under linux?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like the DF needs to be removed _before_ it is converted to ascii.  That seems like a problem with the sendmail product, or something _before_ hitting sendmail.

Comment: @RickJames You are probably right. I'm asking more out of curiosity, but also because we had a weird case with a particular email that create the exact problem described in the IBM document (MS Exchange -> Sendmail  8.14.7). The connection hang for 12 hours and then timeout with a "collect: premature EOM: unexpected close" and "collect: unexpected close on connection from <<<SNIP>>>, sender=<<<SNIP>>>". Fully reproducible.